# How to return 3 result sets from stored proc in entity FWK

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**I am able to fetch first 2 result sets from store procedure using Entity FWK But I am facing error while retrieving the third result set.**

I am using below to execute the store procedure.

```
var results = base.dbcontext.GetData(id)
```

Then i am retrieving the 3 results like below.

```
List<Result1> Result1 = null;
List<Result2> Result2= null;
List<Result3> Result3= null; 
var results = base.dbcontext.GetData(id)
result1 = results.ToList();
Result2 = results.GetNextResult<Result2>().ToList();
Result3 = results.GetNextResult<Result3>().ToList();
```

I am able to fetch the "Result2" result set but getting below exception while retrieving the third result set.

Exception is: **The type parameter 'Result3' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'Result2' returned by the function.**

My .edmx file is like below.

```
<FunctionImport Name="USP_GetKPIDefinitionData" >
  <ReturnType Type="Collection(DBModel.Result1)"/>
  <ReturnType Type="Collection(DBModel.USP_Result2)"/>
  <ReturnType Type="Collection(DBModel.Result3)"/>
  <Parameter Name="Id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
</FunctionImport>
```

Is there any other i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Below is the code.

```
List<Result1> Result1 = null;
List<Result2> Result2= null;
List<Result3> Result3= null; 
var results = base.dbcontext.GetData(id)
result1 = results.ToList();
var data = results.GetNextResult<Result2>()
Result2 = data.ToList();
Result3 = data.GetNextResult<Result3>().ToList();
```